# All PHP files give 500 error unless set to "-rw-r-----"

Tags: php, chmod, http-status-code-500

I noticed a weird error.
All PHP files on my shared hosting fail with 500 error, even empty ones.

After changing their permissions from "-rw-rw-r--" to "-rw-r-----", they started working right away.

What is this happening?

P.S. Error message from logs:

> SoftException in Application.cpp:254: File "......./test.php" is writeable by group

Comment: ...and what was in the server error log?

Comment: and what's the result of `ls -l` versus the user owning the server process.

Comment: ls -l:

-rw-r-----  1 username username       0 Feb  2 15:33 test2.php // file that works
-rw-rw-r--  1 username username       0 Feb  2 15:41 test.php // file that fails

Comment: Error message from logs: SoftException in Application.cpp:254: File "......./test.php" is writeable by group

Comment: The group permissions should be read-only, not read-write.

Comment: It's a security thing. You use something like suexec?

Comment: It looks like an exception from [suPHP](https://www.suphp.org/Home.html) — certainly that throws `SoftExceptions` in its `Application.cpp`. Bear in mind that their web page says that the software is abandoned and not receiving even security patches, so if that really is what you're using, you may want to change your hosting!